# Как написать функцию, которая возвращает NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios7

Доброго времени суток!
Ребята, подскажите, пожалуйста, как написать функцию в `Objective–С`, которая возвращала бы объект класса `NSDictionary`, и возможно ли это вообще?
Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Comment: -(NSDictionary*)getJSON:(NSString*)urlString: (NSData*)params{
    
    NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:15.0];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
 
    if (params != nil) {
        
        [request setHTTPBody:params];
        
    }
    if (session != nil) {
        NSString* s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"PHPSESSID=%@",session];
        [request setValue:s forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cookie"];
    }
 продолжение в следующем комментарии

Comment: NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response;
    NSData *data=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                       returningResponse:&response
                                                   error:&error];
    
    id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
   
   if (session == nil) {
        NSDictionary*d = [jsonObject objectForKey:@"session"];
  продолжение в следующем коментарии

Comment: NSString*sess = [d objectForKey:@"session"];
        NSLog(@"%@",jsonObject);
        session = sess;
   }
    
    
    return jsonObject;
    
}

функция делает http post запрос, сохранияет сессию и возвращает NSDictionary

Comment: спасибо всем

Answer (score 1):

элементарно

```
 - (NSDictionary *)myFunction
 {
     return myDictionary;
 }
```

Comment: нет !!! так не работает!!! но все ровно спасибо!!!

Comment: а что не работает?
естественно, что переменную нужно где-то инициализировать)
чуть ниже написано с сахаром, который доставлят, но вам, судя по всему, нужно без сахара.

Answer (score 1):

Метод:

```
 - (NSDictionary *)dictionary
 { 
     return @{};
 }
```

Функция:

```
 NSDictionary* dictionary(void)
 {
     return @{};
 }
```

---

Литература:

- «Objective-C 2.0 и программирование для Mac»
- Стивен Кочан - «Программирование на Objective-C 2.0»
- [Книги для начинающих программистов под iOS](http://theapplegeek.ru/archives/4146)